# How can I change a LinkedIn group's email digest from every day to every week?

Tags: linkedin, scheduling, configuration, linkedin-groups

Can I change the email digest for a LinkedIn group to be sent less frequently instead of every day?

Being a member of many LinkedIn groups, I get flooded with emails (potentially drowning out important emails) and would like reduce the frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. There is a per-group setting to control the frequency of digest emails. There is an overview for all groups from which it can be set in a batch-like fashion:

1. Settings (upper right, in pop-up under your name) -> "Email Preferences" -> "Set the frequency of group digest emails".
2. Change the popup for one or more groups from "Daily digest email" to "Weekly digest email".

It can also be set under each group:

1. Open a page that is in group context (for example, a discussion in the group or menu "Groups" (in the same row as "Home", "Profile", "Contacts", "Groups", "Jobs", "Inbox", "Companies", "News", and "More") -> "See all" -> click on a group)
2. Then menu "More..." (in the same row as "Discussions", "Members", "Promotions", "Jobs", "Search") -> "Your Settings"
3. Under "Contact Settings, Digest Email" change the popup "Delivery Frequency" from "Daily digest email" to "Weekly digest email".
4. Press button "Save Changes"

---

And to really cut down on the LinkedIn spam:

- Uncheck the option *Send me an email for each new discussion* in the same window.

Comment: LinkedIn does not seem to actually respect the per-week setting...

Comment: Even changing the email address does not seem to be respected (even after 24 hours).